# Do the questions about survival food belong here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Do the questions about survival food belong here?

I've asked questions about how to quickly make snails edible: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24456/how-to-quickly-prepare-snails and it was migrated to *Cooking SE*. I don't think this is the proper site for such questions, since as for me they've could be eaten raw if it would be safe (but it isn't, because of parasites that need to be destroyed).

So, what is wrong with such questions, that they are marked off-topic and migrated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Survival food totally appropriate.

The line is fuzzy, but your original question didn't really (to me) contain any element of "the great outdoors".  The question just boiled down to "how do I cook snails quick"?.

However I could see a fair point that you should have had more feedback and time to edit and I was probably a bit hasty in the migration (not sure if I can migrate back, cooking mods may have to do that).

Comment: So maybe better for me to ask it once again, but with more direct referral to survival situation?

Comment: @lechlukasz -- Given the voting, I'd say yes, re-ask with better wording :)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like this questions migrated BACK to TGO, vote this answer up and I'll go, hat-in-hand to the cooking mods and see what I can do.